# Convert HTML label to button in Bootstrap 3 to toggle a checkbox

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, button, label

I'm using the following HTML label setup to toggle a checkbox which opens a Menu-Panel:

```
<label for="special-menu" class="sp-menu">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Open Special Menu
</label>

<input id="special-menu" class="sl-toggle" type="checkbox">
    <div class="Menu-container">
        ...
    </div">
```

Is there any way **(without js)** to convert it to a button? Something like:

```
<button for="special-menu" class="btn btn-default">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Open Special Menu
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery and javascript:

```js
$("#btn").click(function(){

var checkbox = $('#special-menu').prop('checked');

if(checkbox == true){
$('#special-menu').prop('checked', false);
} 
else{
$('#special-menu').prop('checked', true);
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn" for="special-menu" class="btn btn-default">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Open Special Menu
</button>

<input id="special-menu" class="sl-toggle" type="checkbox">
    <div class="Menu-container">
        ...
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use label in button

```html
    <button  for="special-menu" class="btn btn-default">
        <label for="special-menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Open Special Menu
    </label></button>
    
    <input id="special-menu" class="sl-toggle" type="checkbox">
        <div class="Menu-container">
            ...
        </div>
```

Comment: sure?? see in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3deehg1h/)  this work for me

Comment: Yes - found the problem. In FIREFOX it doesnt toggle in Chrome it does... Any idea how to make it cross-browser compatible

Comment: Oops! no I have not, but you can give a class "btn btn-success" or any btn class  bootstrap , this doesn't need to button, see: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3deehg1h/1/)